# Calculate weight of inputs in a simple equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that we have this equality:

```
4+2+2 = 8
```

weight of `4` in this equality is `4/8=50%`, weight of `2` is `2/8=25%` and weight of `2` is `2/8=25%`. Now suppose that we have this:

```
6-2+11-4 = 11
```

How we can calculate weight of every input to calculate output (11) in this form of equality?

Comment: How did you calculate the weight of $1$ in $4+2+2=8$? Am I misunderstanding what you mean by weight, or is that a typo?

Comment: @DivergentQueries . Thank you for comment. It was typo.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like each term's weight is simply the term divided by the final sum. In general, if we have
$$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n=S,$$
then we can find the weight of the $i^{\text{th}}$ term$-$which we'll call $W_i$$-$ using 
$$W_i=a_i/S.$$

In your equation (for example), the weight of $11$ is $11/11 = 100\%$, and the weight of $-2$ is $-2/11=-18.\overline{18}\%$.